# create a new data frame from existing data frame based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,1,1,0,1,0], [1,0,1,1,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,1], 
[0,0,1,0,0,1]]))
df
```

Now, from data frame df I like to create a new data frame based on condition
Condition: if a column contain three or more than three '1' then the new data frame column value is '1' otherwise '0'

```
expected output of new data frame
    1 0 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,1,1,0,1,0], [1,0,1,1,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,1], 
[0,0,1,0,0,1]]))
df_res = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda c: 1 if np.sum(c) > 2 else 0))

In [6]: df_res
Out[6]: 
   0
0  1
1  0
2  1
3  0
4  0
5  1
```

Instead of `np.sum(c)` you can also do `c.sum()`

And if you want it transposed just do the following instead:

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda c: 1 if c.sum() > 2 else 0)).T
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also get it without `apply`. You could `sum` along the rows, `axis=0`, and creating a boolean with `gt(2)`:

```
res = df.sum(axis=0).gt(2).astype(int)

print(res)

0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    1
dtype: int32
```

As David pointed out, the result of the above is a `series`. If you require a dataframe, you can chain [`to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) at the end of it

Comment: Nice! just small correction is that `res` is of type `pandas.core.series.Series` so one should transform it to DataFrame

Comment: Thanks! Good point. I will add that now.